# How does Mark Knopfler do muting?

Tags: electric-guitar, mute

Out of curiosity, I'd like to know how Mark Knopfler does muting in his playing. By watching some of his performing videos (for example,

) I guess he mutes the strings from the bottom up possibly by his picking hand thumb; but I did not see how he mutes strings from the top down.

This question assumes that he really does muting. I would not be surprised if it turns out to be the case that he just doesn't do it like Neil Young, but to me which is only slightly possible....

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

He uses various muting types.

- You have spotted the thumb muting, which is very effective
- He also mutes with the first three fingers of his right hand (most of his plucking is done with the first two so the third is used a lot in this respect)
- Mark also uses left hand damping, where he slightly releases pressure on the strings
- Right hand palm heel muting is also used

You can see the first three in that video if you watch closely, but I'm not sure whether he uses palm heel muting here.